# Apache mod_wsgi serving rest api and static website on virtualhost

Tags: amazon-ec2, debian, mod-wsgi, web-hosting

So I have an ec2 instance running debian with apache and mod_wsgi to serve my flask rest api and I also have a static web page using react which makes calls to the api to abstract the database logic.

I have got the static web page set up working, but the routing to the /api endpoint I cannot get to call the flask server. I want them to be accessible from the same port so that I can have the static site available at the base / route and the api calls can be made using the same address /api/<API END POINT>. I haven't seen any other questions that address this specific use case so hopefully I'm not completely wrong in this approach.

Here is the virtualhost set up, I've tried setting up an alias for /api, but this seems to be the closest I can get it to work.

```
    LogLevel debug
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front-end
    Alias / /var/www/html/front-end/
    <Directory /var/www/html/front-end>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 WSGIDaemonProcess api python-home=/var/www/html/api/venv threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/html/api/app.wsgi
    <Location "/api">
        WSGIProcessGroup api
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My wsgi file looks like this

```py
activate_this = '/var/www/html/api/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    exec(f.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/api")
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages")
from api import app as application
```

I can see the problem is that when I access the /api endpoint it is looking for the file in /front-end/api/ instead of forwarding that request to the flask server.
I have also tried adding

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:5000/api
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:5000/api
```

Which works but means I have to be running the local dev server which seems un-safe.

Thanks for the help in advance!